# Observe updated StateFlow List from ViewModel in Composable Function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I am trying to update a list item's value and then observing the updated list as a state in the Composable function. The problem is that if I emit a new list then it's observing as expected but not working when I emit the updated list in ViewModel. Attaching Code for a better understanding

```
data class SocialMediaProfile(
    val id: Int,
    val icon: Int,
    var profileUrl: String,
    val siteUrl: String
)
```

//ViewModel

```
val socialMediaProfile = MutableStateFlow<List<SocialMediaProfile>>(listOf())

fun updateSocialMediaProfiles(socialMediaProfiles: List<SocialMediaProfile>) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        socialMediaProfile.value = emptyList() //Working
        socialMediaProfile.value = buildList { addAll(socialMediaProfiles) } //Not Working
    }
}
```

//Collect State FLow List as State in Composable

```
val socialMediaProfileList = viewModel.socialMediaProfile.collectAsState()
Column() {
    socialMediaProfileList.value.forEach {
        val profileUrl = remember {
            mutableStateOf(it.profileUrl)
        }
        InputField(
            text = profileUrl,
            onValueChanged = { s ->
                profileUrl.value = s
                it.profileUrl = s
                viewModel.updateSocialMediaProfiles(socialMediaProfileList.value)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **ArrayList** instead of **List**:

**ViewModel:**

```
private val _socialMediaProfile = MutableStateFlow<ArrayList<SocialMediaProfile>>(arrayListOf())
val socialMediaProfile = _socialMediaProfile.asStateFlow()

fun updateSocialMediaProfiles(socialMediaProfiles: List<SocialMediaProfile>) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _socialMediaProfile.value = emptyList()
        _socialMediaProfile.value.addAll(socialMediaProfiles)
    }
}
```